# Is this text overlay done using Facebook Open Graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

[image: screen-shot from facebook post]

Hello all,

I checked the source code of this blog post and the open graph images tags do not include the text that I've highlighted in the screen shot.  Is there a special open graph tag to add text overlays? Or is it done in a different way?

Here's the link to the blog post: http://www.barakabits.com/2014/04/meet-woman-behind-e-middle-east

Thanks in advance!
Waleed

Comment: There is not. Either they changed the image url so what you see in the story is an old image. Or they serve a special image when Facebook fetch the image

Comment: I checked the source code again and none of the images include the text that appears on the FB post.  My question is still unanswered. Any suggestions on how it's done?

Comment: Either they serve a different image for Facebook by looking at their user agent or IP address or it is an old scrape

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these api links, looks like it's what you need.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative-link-data-image-overlay-spec/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative-link-data-image-layer-spec/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not provide an option for this feature yet.

You can use PHP GD Library functions to prepare and use open graph images with an overlay.

To get an output like the screenshot you provided, you need a source image and a transparent overlay image. Then merge them together to the final open graph image.

For that you need [imagecopy()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) function.

```
<?php

$src = imagecreatefromjpg('source-image.jpg');
$overlay = imagecreatefrompng('transparent-overlay.png');
$overlay_x = 0; // The position of overlay in X axis
$overlay_y = 480; // The position of overlay in Y axis
$overlay_width = 1200;
$overlay_height = 630;


imagecopy($src, $addition, $addtion_x, $addition_y, 0, 0, $overlay_width, $overlay_height);

header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($src);

// Free up the memory
imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($overlay);

?>
```

If you want to use this feature on a WordPress website (like the source website you mentioned) you can follow this tutorial.

https://itsmereal.com/automated-open-graph-image-overlay-for-wordpress

or use this plugin from Github

https://github.com/itsmereal/og-image-overlay